# Need kendo grid column Menu close event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid which has column Menu, do we have any way to trigger event when the column Menu closes?
It has ColumnMenuInit and columnHide and ColumnMenuOpen.
I need onColumnMenu close.
Can this be done in some other way?

Answer (score 2):

In [columnMenuInit](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/columnmenuinit), you can access the kendo popup and bind to its close event:

```
  columnMenuInit: function(e) {
    const field = e.field
    e.container.data('kendoPopup').bind("close", function(e2) {
        console.log("Closed menu for field", field)
    })
  }
```

Working example: https://dojo.telerik.com/AGakEXIY